# How to print out all data from client request to URL in Flask?

Tags: python, debugging, flask

So I want to accept all data that comes to `localhost/verify` and print it onto console in Flask. How to do such thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can print out the whole request inside your function:

```
from flask import request
from pprint import pprint

@your_blueprint.route('/verify'):
   pprint(request)
```

I don't know if this is what you are searching for, hope it can help!